# How to parse select second HTML anchor element within a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JSON response which is returning correctly and have successfully inputted data from it on my HTML page. However, this one JSON value returns some HTML code in which I do not need all of it, just the second anchor element. How would you guys do this?

The code below, the top two work fine. The P element does not. Any ideas? I just get `undefined` in the console.

```
                // get photo url from description JSON value. 

                var imageURL = $(description).find('a')[ 1 ];
                var parseImageURL = $(imageURL).attr('href');


                // get author URL from description JSON value

                var authorURL = $(description).find('a')[ 0 ];
                var parseAuthorURL = $(authorURL).attr('href');


                // get photo description from descriptions JSON value

                var descriptionText = $(description).find('P')[5];
                console.log(descriptionText);
```

Comment: Two things that could have happened: 1) you have got the indexes mixed up (likely since there are lots of `p` elements) 2) You've got some undefined variables (what is `description`?)

Comment: Hey Jack.

That's the thing, description is pretty deep inside the JSON so there's hardly any tags. it is too long to post, but there is only 3 <p> elements and 2 'text' elemetns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parse HTML**

You need to "parse" the HTML. There's (at least) two ways to do it:

[DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) or create an element and stuff the HTML string in there.

The following example shows the second method.

1. In my example, I assign some string to `HTML` but you are getting it in some object that you have parsed from JSON.
2. Create an element. Could be any old element, but I chose `div`
3. assign the HTML string to the `innerHTML` of the element created in step 2
4. use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the node you want. In this example, I selected all of the `p` elements.
5. I simply logged out the second `p`, but in your case, you add it to the page, I assume

```js
let HTML = "<p>something</p><p>else</p>";

let el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = HTML;

let ps = el.querySelectorAll('p');
console.log(ps[1]);
```